# insert .csv file to Redis

Tags: database, csv, redis, nosql, google-colaboratory

I need to insert the information from my .tsv file to Redis. I am using Google Collab and I am not using the redis Python library, but I am using a client that I have installed (out of obligation):

```
%%bash
redis-cli ping
```

```
PONG
```

The issue is that I need to insert the information from a .tsv file with the information from 123663 comments that looks like this:

```
Id  CreationDate    PostId  Score   Text    UserDisplayName UserId
1   2015-10-29T16:31:36.090 1   0   Más tarde añadiré la respuesta, pero si alguien quiere hacer los honores antes...       23
2   2015-10-29T18:03:06.780 1   1   ¡Excelente! Nuestra primera pregunta. :)        4
```

Looking for how to insert it into Redis I saw that you could use an awk command in bash where you parse each line and insert it to Redis. With that information and adapting it to my problem I have used the following:

```
%%bash
awk -F '\t' 'FNR > 1 {gsub(/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]/, "", $5); print "XADD Comments * Id "$1" CreationDate \""$2"\" PostId "$3" Score "$4" Text \""$5"\" UserDisplayName \""$6"\" UserId "$7"\n"}' Comments.tsv | redis-cli --pipe
```

Which in case anyone is wondering gives an output like this:

```
%%bash
awk -F '\t' 'FNR > 1 {gsub(/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]/, "", $5); print "XADD Comments * Id "$1" CreationDate \""$2"\" PostId "$3" Score "$4" Text \""$5"\" UserDisplayName \""$6"\" UserId "$7"\n"}' Comments.tsv | head
```

```
XADD Comments * Id 1 CreationDate "2015-10-29T16:31:36.090" PostId 1 Score 0 Text "Ms tarde aadir la respuesta pero si alguien quiere hacer los honores antes" UserDisplayName "" UserId 23

XADD Comments * Id 2 CreationDate "2015-10-29T18:03:06.780" PostId 1 Score 1 Text "Excelente Nuestra primera pregunta " UserDisplayName "" UserId 4
```

My problem is that it ends in failure and only inserts 103649 comments out of the total. Also, many of the insertions give the following output:

```
ERR wrong number of arguments for 'xadd' command.
```

I don't know if it is because of some problem with the Text field and special characters but I am not able to clean it anymore.

I hope someone can tell me how to fix it or if there is another method to insert the .tsv file (or .csv which I also have) that is simpler or better.

Thank you very much in advance and happy new year! :)

José Adrián.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than getting it fixed, I have figured out how to insert the information correctly.

```
%%bash
redis-cli FT.CREATE commentsIndex ON HASH PREFIX 1 "comment:" SCHEMA \
  Id NUMERIC SORTABLE \
  CreationDate TEXT SORTABLE \
  PostId NUMERIC SORTABLE \
  Score NUMERIC SORTABLE \
  Text TEXT SORTABLE \
  UserDisplayName TEXT SORTABLE \
  UserId TEXT SORTABLE
```

Output:

```
OK
```

And then I inserted the information by applying preprocessing to certain fields of the .tsv.

```
%%bash
awk -F '\t' 'FNR > 1 {
  gsub(/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]/, "", $5);
  gsub(/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]/, "", $6);

  $7 = ($7 == "") ? "nan" : $7;

  comment_id = "comment:" $1;
  print "FT.ADD commentsIndex "comment_id" 1.0 FIELDS Id "$1" CreationDate \""$2"\" PostId "$3" Score "$4" Text \""$5"\" UserDisplayName \""$6"\" UserId "$7"\n"
}' Comments.tsv | redis-cli --pipe
```

Output:

```
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
Last reply received from server.
errors: 0, replies: 123329
```